# Simple Game Engine in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I’m planning on creating a Mortal Kombat-inspired game in JavaScript. I’ve written a basic game engine that manages my game states and creates a game loop.

I just wondered if it could be improved at all? As I’m a web developer by trade and this is my first foray into programming games.

```
/**
 * Game engine.
 */
function GameEngine() {
    this.states = new Array();
    this.currentState;
    this.running = false;
};

GameEngine.prototype.init = function() {
    this.running = true;
};

GameEngine.prototype.changeState = function(state) {
    this.currentState = state;
};

GameEngine.prototype.isRunning = function() {
    return this.running;
};

GameEngine.prototype.handleEvents = function() {
    this.currentState.handleEvents(this);
};

GameEngine.prototype.update = function() {
    this.currentState.update(this);
};

GameEngine.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.currentState.draw(this);
};

/**
 * Base game state state.
 */
function GameState() {};

/**
 * Intro state.
 */
function IntroState() {};

IntroState.prototype = Object.create(GameState.prototype);

IntroState.prototype.handleEvents = function(game) {
    console.log('IntroState::handleEvents');
};

IntroState.prototype.update = function(game) {
    console.log('IntroState::update');
};

IntroState.prototype.draw = function(game) {
    console.log('IntroState::draw');
};

/**
 * Initialises the game.
 */
(function() {
    var game = new GameEngine();
    var gameLoop;
    var frameLength = 500;

    game.init();
    game.changeState(new IntroState());

    gameLoop = setInterval(function() {
        game.handleEvents();
        game.update();
        game.draw();
    }, frameLength);
})();
```

Comment: It's a little hard to code review something this simple it doesn't actually do anything at this moment.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I was on the right track. Obviously I’m not going to write a complete game and then post the code here, as that could potentially be tens of thousands of lines of code.

Comment: That's understandable, a basic game engine is a loop and a redraw/update system. So yes you are good. You should explore other game engines in javascript and see what they do.

Comment: Well the client-code shouldn't have to know about how to setup the game loop. That part should be encapsulated as well. Also, it's a bit verbose and not DRY to type `Constructor.prototype` all the time, you should perhaps do something like `Constructor.prototype = { constructor: Constructor, someFn: function () {}, someOtherFn: function () {} }`. Also have a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-objectorientedjs/

Comment: @plalx Your comment, combined with Steven's comments could work fine as an answer to this question. If you write it as an answer, I'll give you an upvote (and we will have one less unanswered question)

Answer (score 2):

There's really not much to say about this code, so I'll quote a comment posted on this question:

> [...] a basic game engine is a loop and a redraw/update system. So yes you are good. You should explore other game engines in javascript and see what they do. – Steven

Just one thing that's itching: you're declaring `var frameLength = 500;` - I think this is going to bite you later, when you want to adjust frame rate (FPS).

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents:

- GameEngine is most likely going to be a singleton, so there is no reason to add anything to it's prototype really. You can assign init etc. straight to GameEngine.
- If you are going to have the GameEngine functions simply execute the currentState functions, you should at least return `this`, so that the caller can chain calls.
- I am very ambivalent towards `handleEvents`, I would simply listen to mouse clicks and keyboard presses in the old school way and update the data model in your `GameEngine`, then draw the data from the data model every n milliseconds.
- As retailcoder mentioned, you will probably have to think how you want to maintain a steady fps, just calling those functions every x milliseconds is not going to cut it most likely.

Answer (score -2):

Just a general tip in regard to the comments...

It's not recommended to use `/* */` comment blocks in your code. The reason for that is because in Javascript, that character pair can occur in regular expression literals as well. Comment blocks are therefore not safe for commenting blocks of code.

A better alternative is to generally stick to line comments (`//`) whenever possible and save block comments for formal documentation and for commenting out.

Comment: I have to disagree with you about this. I see no reason to avoid `/* */` comments just because it can be occur in regex.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I agree with you, but this question needs an upvoted answer :)

Comment: @retailcoder I know, but upvoted answers should be **useful** answers :) Thanks for adding a better one.

Comment: So you say to avoid comments blocks, then say save them for formal documentation? Be consistent. Also, I’ve never had a problem with comments being interpreted as regular expression literals and vice versa.